# Why does importing NLTK result in importing string from unrelated file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

When I import NLTK in a specific script and run the code, the Shell prints a string from a totally different script as well in the form of a list. None of the variables share names, and the other script does not use NLTK, and I have never had this issue before. The two scripts are in the same folder. The code shown here is the entire script, the unwanted string it prints comes from another .py file.

I have tried changing the names of the variables and the function, the name of the .py file and moving the import statement in and out of the function. I have also tried restarting the shell. The result is always the same: It prints a string from an unrelated file. I know that I don't need NLTK at this stage, but the problem exists none the less.

```
import nltk  

def ordforraad(streng):  

    print(streng)

tekst = 'Hello'  
ordforraad(tekst)
```

I expect it to just print 'Hello', but it also prints something from an exercise I did once on regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're using a jupyter notebook and you have ran some other functions above. Restart the kernel and only run these lines. It works as expected.

```
>>> import nltk  
>>> def ordforraad(streng):
...     print(streng)
... 
>>> ordforraad(tekst)
Hello
```